# How do I output subtasks to the diagram d3.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, d3.js

There is an array of objects. Objects are tasks. Each object has an array of nested objects. Nested objects are subtasks.

In controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Gantt()
    {
        var applicationContext = await _context.GisTask
            .Include(g => g.StatusTask).Where(g => g.StatusTask.Name == "В работе")
            .Include(g => g.Category)
            .Include(g => g.Customer)
            .Include(g => g.User)
            .Include(g => g.ControleUser)
            .Include(g => g.GisComments)
            .Include(g => g.SecondTasks)
            .OrderBy(g => g.EndDateTime)
            .ToListAsync();
        //JsonConvert.SerializeObject((from a in db.Events where a.Active select a).ToList(), Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings()
        //{
        //    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        //}
        return View(applicationContext);
    }
```

In View

```
var datagantt = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
console.log(datagantt);

var height = 500,
    width = 1200,
    margin = 30; // отступ
var offset = 50; // смещение между значениями на осях
// добавляем к оси отступы слева и справа
var xAxisLength = width - 2 * margin;
var yAxisLength = height - 2 * margin;
var svg; //объект svg, который будет содержать визуализацию
var createTimeDataMassiv = [];
var endTimeDataMassiv = [];

datagantt.forEach(function (d) {
    createTimeDataMassiv.push(d.createDateTime);
    endTimeDataMassiv.push(d.endDateTime);
});

var svg = d3.select("div.gantt").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var scaleX = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(d3.min(d3.values(createTimeDataMassiv))), new Date(d3.max(d3.values(endTimeDataMassiv)))])
    .range([0, xAxisLength])
    .nice();

var scaleY = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, yAxisLength])
    .domain(datagantt.map(function (d) { return d.name; }));

// создание осей
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(scaleX)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d.%m'))
    .ticks(22);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(scaleY);
// добавляем элемент с осями на страницу
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform",  // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо
    "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick")
    .append("line") // добавляем линию
    .classed("grid-line", true) // добавляем класс
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", - (height - 2 * margin));  

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "body")
    .attr("transform",  // сдвиг объекта вправо
    "translate(" + margin + "," + margin*2 + ")");

g.selectAll("rect.bar")
    .data(datagantt)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar");

g.selectAll("rect.bar")
    .data(datagantt)
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return scaleX(new Date(d.createDateTime));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return scaleY(d.name);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return 14;
    })
    .attr('width', 0) // Исходная ширина элемента до начала анимации
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return scaleX(new Date(d.endDateTime)) - scaleX(new Date(d.createDateTime));
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });
```

[image]

How do I output subtasks to the diagram d3.js? It is required to display subtasks under each task. At me it turned out to deduce only tasks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Simply dumping your code and asking how do I do this won't get any responses. You need to show what you have tried, and show where you are having trouble, we won't write the code for you

Comment: If I knew the answer to my question, I would not ask it. I have a problem that I can not decide for a long time. I can not figure out how to bring to the task diagram together with the subtasks. I can deduce separately tasks, I can deduce separately subtasks. I can not bring them together so that under each task there are subtasks. I'm a beginner programmer, I do not know much. If you know how to solve this issue, please help.

Comment: ok, my apologies for not being helpful, I'm trying to tell you there is an etiquette for using SO. Simply dumping your code and asking 'how do I do this?' isn't going to work. Please show what you have tried, and where you think the problem is (and any error messages you get)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Previously, I had an array of objects that contained other objects. I brought all the subtasks to the same level with the tasks in the new array. I created one common array in such a way that after each task there were its subtasks. Also, during the execution of the cycle, subtasks were sorted by the end date.

```
var datagantt = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));

var second = [];

datagantt.forEach(function (item) {
    second.push(item);
    item.secondTasks
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.endDateTime == b.endDateTime)
                return 0;
            if (a.endDateTime < b.endDateTime)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1; 
        })
        .forEach(function (d) {
        second.push(d);
    })
});
```

It was so
[{0 task}, {1 task}, {2 task}, {3 task: subtasks[{0 subtask}{1 subtask}{3 subtask}]}]

it became so [{0 task}, {1 task}, {2 task}, {3 task}, {0 subtask in 3 task}, {1 subtask in 3 task}, {3 subtask in 3 task}, {4 task}, {0 subtask in 4 task}, {1 subtask in 4 task}]

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpNLv.png)